# how to make body not scroll through menu bar

Tags: javascript, css

I want when touching the menu, the body to be non scrollable. I can scroll the body when scrolling on main content but i dont want to scroll the body when touching the mobile menu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the menu “onOpen” even should trigger a change in the body’s style to `overflow: hidden;` and menu “onClose” event should trigger a change in body’s style to `overflow: auto;`

Without further details on your case, it’s hard to elaborate.